# PCA For Face Recognition: OpenCV

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I am Working on Face Recognition using OpenCV c++: I have tested the code OpenCV provides for PCA: It returns me Eigen Vectors and Mean, But how can i use that to test an image for Recognition?

I read Articles to understand the process of PCA..I can implement the covariance Matrix,weights and all manually but I wanted to try OpenCV PCA function.

Please Do help

Comment: from where you're now, the actual face recognition is just projecting the images to pca-space( means multiplying them with the eigenvector-Mat) and do a L2 comparison between your train and the test image in that space.

Comment: The PCA function of opencv gives me just the eigen vectors of the the input training image (i have kept Number of components to keep for the PCA: 10)  and i dont know how to get all the eigen vectors from the pca by opencv

Comment: I didnt Understand the projecting the images to pca-space...Can you please elaborate???....Thanks

Comment: given, that you did not supply 1 image to the pca, but *all* your (flattened) train images, the [pca](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/contrib/src/facerec.cpp#L464) of that gives you the Mat of eigenvectors. then, per image,  [you subtract the mean, and make a matrix-mult](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/contrib/src/lda.cpp#L206). (and probably save the results)

Comment: Will try that and post wether I got or not...Thanks For Help

Comment: btw, there is a [FaceRecognizer class](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html) doing all of it already

Comment: So Like I had 4 images of 1 person(had 3 people in total)...I used 3 images of each person for training(at a single instant)..i made each into row vector then formed a matrix with all the 9 row vectors(3 people each with 3 training images) and supplied it to pca function(number of components=20)...it gave me back a mean ,9 eigenvectors and 9 eigen values..so the Eigen vectors make a matrix. Now using that 4th  image of every person as test images i have to do a L2 comparison...right?

Comment: but all the images give similar results..where am I wrong?
I have not used the weights system in the eigenfaces.

Comment: "but all the images give similar results" - now, that's where the *real* work starts. you need more images, like 20 per person. also, good cropping is essential, equalizeHist, maybe. and then, eigenfaces might not be the best tool on the market (usually, it's just slightly better than a straight pixel comparison..) [also, i'm totally biased towards lbph derivates, since i'm currently working on that a bit....;]

Comment: I have used DCT but that gives better results then this...actually i think just getting the eigenface and L2 comparison is where i am going wrong...there is an intermediate step i am missing

Comment: if you really want your mind blown: [Surpassing Human-Level Face Verification Performance on LFW with GaussianFace](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.3840)

Comment: Does the eigenfacerecognizer() by opencv does the same thing as i am doin above with function PCA ?

Comment: "same thing as i am doin above with function PCA ?" - i think so.

Comment: I guess I will have to make a weight vector for each Eigen Face

Answer (score 0):

Take a look the links below I think it should be useful:

Opencv's FaceRecognizer class:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html

Eigenfaces in OpenCV

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#eigenfaces-in-opencv

Comment: Thanks For replying ...I have already gone through them already(before asking the question)...How can i know the process happening iside these functions:- 
eigenfacerecognizer(),
train(),
predictLabel().

Comment: Actually i want to know that once I have All the eigen faces from the training data and a test image what should I do to get the results?...Basically the next step after training...In the above(You mentioned) example the opencv function predicts Label but i want to try that manually just to learn.

Comment: Eigen faces is a multidimentional coordinate system. Origin is meanface. Face is a point in this coordinate system. Coefficients you get after projection is coordinates of the face in this coordinate system. If you want measure similarity you just measure distance between points. Distance can be measured in different ways, most popular are Euclidian metric and Mahalanobis metric, the second one gives more precice results. Btw openCV is opensource, so you can look at implementations of functions you interested.